# Populate Unit Cost for Serialized Item in custom field SOLine

Tags: acumatica

I need to populate a custom column (User Defined Cost) in SOLine from a Serialized Item Unit Cost from Purchase Receipts with the same Lot/Serial Number (screenshot 1). If the item has splited Lot/Serial number (screenshot 2) then respective unit cost I have to read based on Lot/Serial number user enters in SOLine item.

I have already written SOLine_RowPersisting event to handle if the item is not splited but not sure how to find if there is a splited Serialized items. Below is the code for SOLine_RowPersisting event. Please suggest.

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
    SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
    if (row == null)
        return;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.LotSerialNbr))
    {
        SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

        //select UnitCost, * from POReceiptLine where CompanyID = 2 and ReceiptNbr = 'PR004082' and InventoryID = '8502' and LotSerialNbr = 'SUB1703210365'
        //select LotSerialNbr, * from POReceiptLineSplit where CompanyID = 2 and InventoryID = '8502' and LotSerialNbr = 'SUB1704270366'

        //TODO : How to get it from POReceiptLineSplit also

        POReceiptLine poRow = PXSelect<POReceiptLine,
                        Where<POReceiptLine.inventoryID, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.inventoryID>>,
                            And<POReceiptLine.lotSerialNbr, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.lotSerialNbr>>,
                            And<POReceiptLine.pOType, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.pOType>>>>>>.Select(graph, row.InventoryID, row.LotSerialNbr, "RO");

        SOLineExtension ext = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>(row);
        ext.UsrUserDefinedCost = poRow.UnitCost;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot 1**:-
[image]
**Screenshot 2**:-
[image]

Comment: There is SOLineSplits which is the Allocation of the SOLine and POReceiptLineSplit for POReceiptLines.You can use BQL to get current line allocation and do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is SOLineSplit_LotSerialNbr_FieldUpdated event need to extend in SOOrder Extension and POReceiptLine_RowSelected in POReceiptEntry Extension. Below code will help get unit cost from purchase receipt.

```html
POReceiptLine poRow = PXSelectJoin<POReceiptLine,
 LeftJoin<POReceiptLineSplit,
  On<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<POReceiptLineSplit.receiptNbr>,
   And<POReceiptLine.inventoryID, Equal<POReceiptLineSplit.inventoryID>,
   And<POReceiptLine.lineNbr, Equal<POReceiptLineSplit.lineNbr>>>>>,
 Where<POReceiptLine.inventoryID, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.inventoryID>>,
   And<POReceiptLineSplit.lotSerialNbr, Equal<Required<POReceiptLineSplit.lotSerialNbr>>,
   And<POReceiptLine.receiptType, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.receiptType>>>>>>.Select(graph, row.InventoryID, row.LotSerialNbr, "RT");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on the POReceiptLineSplit records from the 'splits' DataView of the Base DAC.

To do that, open the grid in Acumatica, hold Control+Alt and click on it. This will bring a popup with the DAC name of the records contained in the grid.
[image: DAC]

From there select your customization project. Click on 'Grid: splits', the DataMember property of the grid is 'splits'. This is the name of the DataView from the Base class.
[image: DataView]

With that information, you can iterate content of the grid from the graph extension. Note that we use the Base prefix because we reference the base graph from within the extension.

```
       foreach (POReceiptLineSplit split in Base.splits.Select())
       {
          PXTrace.WriteInformation("ReceiptNbr: {0}{1}LineNbr: {2}{3}SplitLineNbr: {4}",
                                   split.ReceiptNbr, Environment.NewLine,
                                   split.LineNbr, Environment.NewLine,
                                   split.SplitLineNbr);
       }
```

Comment: With that info, how can I update the value in  custom field in SO

Comment: It depends on use case, whether or not field is bound/unbound and should raise events or not. I see you have: SOLineExtension ext = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>(row);
        ext.UsrUserDefinedCost = poRow.UnitCost;

Comment: To persist to Database you should add: PXCache<SOLine>.Update(row); below these lines.

Comment: Row persisting event might be a bit late to call update. If you can, move that code in an event raised before the Persist operation is executed. SOLine_LotSerialNbr_FieldUpdated might be appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I do not think SOLine_LotSerialNbr_FieldUpdated will get executed from POReceipt screen.